# How to automate adding DLL references in a vb6 exe project?

Tags: dll, com, vb6

I have a vb6 exe project that calls a vb6 DLL. Both of them are written by me. Every time I compile the vb6 DLL after doing some changes. I have to open the exe project, re-select the compiled DLL, before I can run/compile the exe. How can I automate above process ? I have tried to edit the vbp file, replace the corresponding DLL row with the GUID of the compiled DLL but not success (may be I got a wrong GUID). Actually, I have more than 10 DLLs in the exe project and some DLL even refer another DLL....so any script or method I can automate the process? Thanks.

Comment: If you recompile the DLL with binary compatibility configured (into the path where the DLL is registered)  it will work seamlessly, See https://www.techrepublic.com/article/demystifying-version-compatibility-settings-in-visual-basic/

Comment: You can also add the DLL project to the EXE project and debug them all together as one if you create a Project Group and add both (or more) VBPs.

Comment: Hi Alex, I know using "binary compatibility" to compile DLLs can avoid the need of re-compile the EXE every time. But I'm not preferred to do this because it is quite dangerous that in case if I have changed something in an existing class method, for example added a new non-optional parameter, but forgot to change the corresponding function calling code in exe. It won't prompt any error message to remind me during start running the program, until running to that line of code. Anyway, the article does help for me to understand more the details of COM operation. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use project compatibility instead of binary compatibility. You don't necessarily need binary compatibility if no one else is using your DLL.

> From msdn
>
> > When Should I Use Version Compatibility?
> >
> > ...
> >
> > **Project Compatibility:** Each time you compile the component the type
> > library identifier is kept, *so that your test projects can maintain
> > their references to the component project.* All class IDs from the
> > previous version are maintained; interface IDs are changed only for
> > classes that are no longer binary-compatible with their earlier
> > counterparts.

(Not sure what the original MSDN page was, but I found this copy of it [here](https://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?274506-Project-Compatability-v-s-Binary-Compatability&s=670b7cd028c72a9001bf026dc400907f&p=857736#post857736).)

If you actually want to inspect the compiled DLL to see what all these IDs are that the article refers to, run OLEView and bind to typelib of your DLL. It will "decompile" the typelib of the DLL where you can see these details. If you recompile it and then diff the typelib text you'll see just how it changed.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I do agree with you that "binary compatibility" is not necessary. But do you know how can I automate the DLLs reference in .vbp ? instead of select the DLL files one by one manually ?

Comment: Why do the references change? They should remain in the saved VBP

Comment: As I am not using "binary compatibility" to compile the DLLs so that the GUID of those DLLs will be changed. For example, below is a row in my VBP 'Reference=*\G{544395AB-041E-43C5-B3FA-A60775C9E308}#1.0#0#\\FILESERVER\Production\COM\FTSTUP\Master\FTSTUP.dll#FTSTUP' that the GUID in "*\G{?????}#..." will be changed. I have to manual select the DLL file in VB6 IDE for each DLL. Now, I want to generate the VBP file so that I don't need to do it manually every time. But I don't know how to get the latest GUID, tried some methods but seems failed. Any suggestion ?

Comment: If you use project or binary comp then those GUIDs should not change. Have you tried that?

Comment: I don't want to use "binary compatibility" because I think it is dangerous that if I changed the function interface in DLL (e.g. added a new parameter) it won't prompt error until run to that line of code.

Comment: Did you try "project compatibility"? Which as noted above, is not the same as "binary" compatibility.

Comment: I do more tests first. Thanks for the help.